# Group array items before looping through then in PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have an array I cant easily sort. I have a list of values, that I explode into an array, which leaves me with something like;

- 11:54
- 11:120
- 11:53
- 22:20
- 43:11
- 55:199
- 22:83

The first part before the : is a category heading and the second value, a sub category.

So I want to now loop through this array putting like minding items together. So group all the category headings, so I can them loop through those putting the sub categories back in a comma seperated list (for use as an IN statement in SQL)

In the above example, that would produce something like;

```
$inStatement1 = "(54,120,53)"
$inStatement2 = "(20,83)"
$inStatement3 = "(11)"
$inStatement4 = "(199)"
```

So all the sub cats of the 11s grouped, 22s grouped etc etc.

I just cannot get the logic to loop through the original list and being able to group together all the subcategories that belong in that group.

Hope that makes sense?!

Any ideas please?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an associative array to store the categories and elements

```
$strings = array(
"11:54",
"11:120",
"11:53",
"22:20",
"43:11",
"55:199",
"22:83"
);

$categories = array();

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $exploded = explode(':',$string);
    $head = $exploded[0];
    $sub = $exploded[1];

    if (!isset($categories[$head])) $categories[$head] = array();
    $categories[$head][] = $sub;
}

print_r($categories);
```

this will produce:

```
Array
(
    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 54
            [1] => 120
            [2] => 53
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 83
        )

    [43] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
        )

    [55] => Array
        (
            [0] => 199
        )

)
```

you can then use implode to combine the into the strings you want

```
$imploded = array();
foreach ($categories as $head => $subs) {
    $imploded[$head] = '"('.implode(',',$subs).')"';
}

print_r($imploded);
```

which will give you your strings:

```
Array
(
    [11] => "(54,120,53)"
    [22] => "(20,83)"
    [43] => "(11)"
    [55] => "(199)"
)
```

Comment: Damn... that looks like a great solution!! Will give it a go in the morning when I'm back working on it and will update - but thanks so far!

Comment: Couldnt wait - had to test it! Works perfectly, thank you so much Samuel!